# Viktor Erofeyev "The Akimuds": Animal motif

Tags: symbolism, russian-language, viktor-erofeyev, the-akimuds

In the SF/Fantasy/political satire "The Akimuds" by Viktor Erofeyev, selfsame Akimuds (sort of a stand-in for God, Jesus and the angels) claim they are ducks. Now, "doves" would have been obvious, from christian iconology, but ducks? I have the nagging feeling there is a Russian pun or cultural reference behind this (just like in Viktor Pelewin's "The Sacred Book of the Werewolf" with the werevixen Ahuli) but of course I know zilch about that. Thus:

Ducks? Thanks. (Always wanted to say that :-)

Comment: The pun is that Akimud is a syllable swap of Mudaki. Yet another swear word, just like A Huli. I may try to expand, but it will take a dissertation.